# Removing or changing table border spacing

Tags: tables

I'm requiring the use of a tabular environment within each item of an itemize environment. However, owing to the default table border spacing, there exists some extra amount of spacing between the item label and the first column of the table. The same applies between the rightmost column and the right margin of my document.

[image]

Notice how the left table border in the first item is aligned with the letter 'T' of the word "This" from the second item. I wish to remove the spacing between the left table border and the text "Column 1 Text" so that 'C' starts from the same point as 'T'. The same applies for the rightmost column as well. The horizontal rule demonstrates the actual text width.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Could you paste a minimal working example and mark the unwanted space in the resulting output?

Comment: a example of what u want might come handy.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}` the `@{}` at start and end  removes the outer padding but leaves the column sep between columns

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
```

The `@{}` at start and end removes the outer padding but leaves the column separation between columns.