How can I make a table take all space inside a tcoorbox so the it leaves no margins?
I'm trying to use this code to make a box with two differently coloured sections inside:
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!20,blue,size=small,
            width=\linewidth,
            title style={color=blue},
            subtitle style={coltitle=black, boxrule=0pt, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt, colback=white},
            title={TITLE}]
        \noindent
        {\rowcolors{1}{white}{blue!20}
        \begin{tabular}{ c c }
            \textbf{Trigger: }&First Field \\
            \textbf{Effect: }&Second Field  
        \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

what I'm trying to do is something like this:

but what I'm actually getting is this:

how can I arrange the table inside the box to get the rsult I want?

Its not absolutely clear, but IMHO your problem are the column separation spaces before the first and maybe also after the last column. You can remove them as usual adding @{} before and after the last column in the column declaration: \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}. I'm sure there is already a question about this, but currently cannot find it.

BTW: tcolorbox also provides keys tabulars, tabulars*, tabularx etc.

This question is similar to: Indent and spacing in tables (or: How to do it better?). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Or maybe this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91058/removing-or-changing-table-border-spacing

the solution of adding @{} almost works: now wy columns acn fill the whole horizontal space. The only problem is the bottom row sticks out over the cut corner

I cannot compile your sample code under MacTeX2024 (with all updates applied). I get the following error message: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/blue' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it..

That's weird, but you can put really any color in there, that's not the important part.

THanks for the pointers but while those are good answers which I'll save non of them worked. Here is how I hacked together a solution.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!20,blue,size=small,
            width=\linewidth,
            title style={color=blue},
            subtitle style={coltitle=black, boxrule=0pt, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt, colback=white},
            title={TITLE},
%%%         put in overlay line to cover the vertical space left above
            overlay={
                \draw[line width = 6pt, blue] (title.south east) --  (title.south west) {};]
        \noindent
%%%     put the table inside a raisebox, not to raise it but to lower the text under
        \raisebox{0.8em}{
             \rowcolors{1}{white}{blue!10}
             \begin{tabular}{ @{}m{\linewidth}@{} }
                 \noindent\textbf{Trigger: }First Field
             \end{tabular}
        }
%%%     took the second field out of the table so it doesn't cover the cut corner
        \noindent\textbf{Effect: }Second Field
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

